# Проблема с кодировкой при чтении файла на кириллице

Tags: c#

[image]

Хочу чтобы в массиве находились города написанные на русском языке и чтобы их можно было выводить на консоль. Но при выводе получаю знаки "?" вместо букв. Уже использовал кодировки 1251 (Windows) и 65001 (UTF-8).

Comment: возможно дело в кодеровке cmd? Если просто сделать `Console.Write("русский текст");` - то ывведется нормально?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, да выводится нормально.

Comment: new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), true)

Comment: @Vasya Milovidov, вот такую ошибку выводит: System.NotSupportedException: "No data is available for encoding 1251. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method."

Answer (score 2):

Решил проблему. Надо было скачать NuGet пакет System.Text.Encoding.CodePages и вначале метода Main добавить Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

Comment: А файл то сам в какой кодировке? Откройте его, к примеру, в Notepad++, там будет написано. Я к тому, что возможно без пакетов можно обойтись.

Comment: Видимо исходник в кодировке 1251. Кодировка 1251 не предустановлена в дефолтных кодировках.